# How to restore one database from a .sql file in which there are two databases?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I was sent a `.sql` file in which there are two databases. Previously, I only dealt with `.sql` files in which there is one database. I also can't ask to send databases in different files.

Earlier I used this command:

```
psql -d first_db < /Users/colibri/Desktop/first_db.sql
```

*Databases on the server and locally have different names.*

Tell me, please, how can I now restore a specific database from a file in which there are several?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Use an editor to delete everything except the database you want from the SQL file.
- Restore the whole file and then drop the database you don't need.

The file was probably generated with `pg_dumpall`. Use `pg_dump` to dump a single database.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the output of pg_dumpall and the file is too big to edit with something like vi, you can use a stream editor to isolate just what you want.

```
perl -ne 'print if /^\\connect foobar/.../^\\connect/' < old.sql > new.sql
```

The last dozen or so lines that this captures will be setting up for and creating the next database it wants to restore, so you might need to tinker with this a bit to get rid of those if you don't want it to attempt to create that database while you replay.  You could change the ending landmark to something like the below so that it ends earlier, but that is more likely to hit false positives (where the data itself contains the magic string) than the '^\connect' landmark is.

```
perl -ne 'print if /^\\connect foobar/.../^-- PostgreSQL database dump complete/'
```